# Extending Django Flatpages - logout

Tags: python, django, django-flatpages

I'm creating a simple Django app (1.3.1) running off virtualenv.  It's up and running on WebFaction.  It's simple enough to only warrant using Flatpages - there is still a bit of enhancement I'd like to make to FlatPages so I'm simply extending the model - nothing complicated.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage

class ExtendedFlatPage(FlatPage):
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["order"]
        verbose_name = "Page"
```

The problem has to do with logging out.  When I try to log out from the entry point to the site there are no problems i.e. http://{domainname}/admin/logout/  However, when I try to log out of the system from further within the admin site - an example is within a list of extended FlatPages http://{domainname}/admin/basic/extendedflatpage/ then logging out (http://{domainname}/admin/basic/extendedflatpage/logout/) generates an error, boiling down to the final observation

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'logout'
```

Full traceback at bottom of entry.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^favicon\.ico$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/static/images/favicon.ico'}),
)
```

Hunting around on the internet brought back the [following page](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10061#comment:21) with a suggestion for a fix.  The problem is, I can't seem to get this to work - the way I tried to implement this was to adjust the urls.py as follows:

```
...
admin.autodiscover()
admin.site.root_path = '/admin/' #should this go here?
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 307, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 79, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 197, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 217, in inner
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/revisions.py", line 279, in do_revision_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/admin.py", line 362, in change_view
    return super(VersionAdmin, self).change_view(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 28, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 24, in bound_func
    return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 217, in inner
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 947, in change_view
    obj = self.get_object(request, unquote(object_id))

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 451, in get_object
    return queryset.get(pk=object_id)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 341, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 550, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 568, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1194, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1129, in add_filter
    connector)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 67, in add
    value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 316, in prepare
    return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 136, in get_prep_lookup
    return self._pk_trace(value, 'get_prep_lookup', lookup_type)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 209, in _pk_trace
    v = getattr(field, prep_func)(lookup_type, v, **kwargs)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 292, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.get_prep_value(value)

  File "/home/niceguydave/.virtualenvs/iwama/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 479, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'logout'


<WSGIRequest
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{'csrftoken': '7cad0c7ee5b93f897e82934aac3f9224',
 'sessionid': 'b7440ccc530704ca15b315f8f1f9f7ed'},
META:{'CSRF_COOKIE': '7cad0c7ee5b93f897e82934aac3f9224',
 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs',
 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'sessionid=b7440ccc530704ca15b315f8f1f9f7ed; csrftoken=7cad0c7ee5b93f897e82934aac3f9224',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'www.iwamaaikidocornwall.com',
 'HTTP_HTTPS': 'off',
 'HTTP_HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http',
 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://www.iwamaaikidocornwall.com/admin/basic/extendedflatpage/',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10_4_11; en) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.1.3 Safari/533.19.4',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '89.241.106.48',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST': 'www.iwamaaikidocornwall.com',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER': 'www.iwamaaikidocornwall.com',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL': 'off',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/admin/basic/extendedflatpage/logout/',
 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/niceguydave/webapps/iwama/production.wsgi/admin/basic/extendedflatpage/logout/',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '40468',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'REQUEST_URI': '/admin/basic/extendedflatpage/logout/',
 'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/home/niceguydave/webapps/iwama/production.wsgi',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'SERVER_ADMIN': '[no address given]',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'www.iwamaaikidocornwall.com',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
 'SERVER_SIGNATURE': '',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3',
 'mod_wsgi.application_group': 'web318.webfaction.com|',
 'mod_wsgi.callable_object': 'application',
 'mod_wsgi.handler_script': '',
 'mod_wsgi.input_chunked': '0',
 'mod_wsgi.listener_host': '',
 'mod_wsgi.listener_port': '47425',
 'mod_wsgi.process_group': 'iwama',
 'mod_wsgi.request_handler': 'wsgi-script',
 'mod_wsgi.script_reloading': '1',
 'mod_wsgi.version': (3, 3),
 'wsgi.errors': <mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x7f5a450c8f30>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0x7f5a44eb2828>,
 'wsgi.input': <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7f5a44e833b0>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
 'wsgi.multithread': True,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 1)}>
```

### Update 05/07/2012

I've taken some of the observations in the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037558/hacking-django-admin-hooks-for-login-logout) and applied to the app for a fix  and have created a new view within my extended Flatpage app

**views.py**

```
def logout(request):
    from django.contrib.auth.views import logout
    return logout(request)
```

I've then imported this view into urls.py and am calling this

**urls.py**

```
...
from basic.views import logout as custom_logout
...
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'/logout/$', custom_logout),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
...
```

Although this now fixes my problem, it seems as if I'm 'patching' things somewhat.

Could anyone please suggest a neater way of doing this? Or does the patch I've applied here seems a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: please post the whole traceback.